# Jquery selector question

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a working selector but I just wondered whether there was another way I could write it.  Here's the html structure:

```
<ul class="TopList">
    <li class="headTitle">
                <a href="#">THIS IS TEXT I WANT TO SELECT</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="list1">item 1</li>
            <li id="list2">item 2</li>
            <li id="list3">item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have a click event attached to the nested listitems.  In the click event I am trying to select the anchor tag.  I have used the follwing selector:

```
$(this).parents('li').children('a')
```

Is this the most efficient way of selecting the anchor tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably look for the class `headTitle` as well just to play it safe.  Also, [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) is a better function for scanning for the closest parent as `.parents()` could match multiple `<li>` items

```
$(this).closest('li.headTitle').children('a')
```